# Add Binding To IIS Without Recycling Application

Tags: c#, iis

We have an application that allows us to associate multiple URLs and we want to allow our customers to add new URLs themselves, we have the following code which successfully adds the bindings:

```
  using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
  {
    var site = serverManager.Sites["SITENAME"];
    var binding = site.Bindings.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Host == hostName);
    if (binding == null)
    {
      binding = site.Bindings.CreateElement("binding");
      binding["protocol"] = "http";
      string ip = "*";
      string port = "80";
      binding["bindingInformation"] = string.Format(@"{0}:{1}:{2}", ip, port, hostName);

      site.Bindings.Add(binding);
      serverManager.CommitChanges();
    }
  }
```

The issue we have is that this causes the application to recycle, I have tested this on our solution using local IIS and the Appliation_Start does get hit again.  I have also manually added a binding from IIS which also causes an recycle.  While I suspect the answer is no is their a solution to adding a binding programatically without causing the application to recycle?

Comment: Adding a binding will cause an Application Domain recycle, and it is by design. You can try Peter's suggestion mentioned above, but I would strongly discourage doing it, since there could be other configuration changes that won't come to affect until you change your configuration + recycle the application domain.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to change the setting `Disable Recycling for Configuration Changes` on the application pool that is hosting your site.

In PowerShell:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add[@name='MyPool']/recycling" -name "disallowRotationOnConfigChange" -value "True"
```

A quick test here showed that adding/removing bindings didn't unload the current AppDomain anymore after changing that setting.

Even if that works, you want to test this for a while to make sure it doesn't break anything else.